# What is the purpose of the QWERDF Replacement Key Caps?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Keyboards often come with an extra set of key caps for WASD keys, designed for improved use controlling movement in gaming.

However, I also note that an extra set of QWERDF keys is also often included. What is the use case for those?

Answer (score 2):

#### An extra set of QWERDF keys is also often included

These are for [MOBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplayer_online_battle_arena) (Multiplayer online battle arena) games:

> Whether you see the world at an isometric angle or from a first-person view, the HyperX FPS & MOBA Gaming Keycaps Upgrade Kit will give your most important keys a tactile feel for a tactical advantage. The Gaming Keycaps have been designed for use in either an FPS or MOBA setup, and they’re textured for grip, coated for durability and come in stylish, striking colours.

The WASD keys are used for [FPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-person_shooter) (First person shooter) games.

Source https://www.hyperxgaming.com/unitedkingdom/en/keyboards/keyboard-accessories/fps-and-moba-gaming-keycaps